# Create two rows for each unique value in column and subtract

Tags: excel, vba, unique, rows, subtraction

I have a list of projects in Excel. Each project has three rows (act, plan, fcst) and many columns (one column = one month).

[image]

What I would like to do is following:

A) for each unique value in column D (project #) add two rows | Completed

B) subtract plan - actual in one of new rows

C) subtract fcst - actual in second of new rows

A*) create two new rows and copy
   data from columns A:AE for each unique value in column D (project #)
   | Optional - I can handle option A), but A* would be a better one.

**Does anyone know how to write a code to do points B, C, A*? I have no clue how to tackle that.**

This is the final output that I would like to see (yellow and orange rows are new ones that I want macro to create for each unique project# in column D):
[image: Final_Output]

Text in AF is always either "Plan $000's" or "Actual $000's" or "Forecast $000's", for each project (i.e. each single project has these three rows; no less, no more).

Data is sorted per impact # (column D). Meaning that first three rows are related to project #123, next three are related to project #129, next three to project #761, etc.

We are allowed to play (sort, filter, etc.) with the data as long as we get the desired result. :-)

Below is the code I have right now... it is quite poor:

```
Sub CreateAndCompare() 
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim dic As Object
Dim ky As Variant
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheets("Impact")
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cl In rng
    If Not dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
        dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Value
    End If
Next cl

For Each ky In dic.keys
      lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("d2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
      Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = dic(ky)
      Cells(lastrow + 2, 4).Value = dic(ky)


Next ky

End Sub
```

thank you!

Comment: Well, and what is your question? You didn't ask one yet. • Also I think it would help if you could include a screen shot of your worksheet.

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: Sorry for bothering again but can you also show a screen shot how it would look like *after* your macro? How should your result look like? • And is the text in AF always like `Plan $000's`, `Actual $000's` or does it change? • Another question: Is your data sorted in any way and are we allowed to re-sort it?

Comment: Amended. Thank you for guidance. Let me know if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. :-)

I have created an extra column AG which concatenates Impact# & Purpose (columns D&AF).

However, it takes ~15 minutes to execute the code.

**Is anyone able to suggest what should I change to make it faster?**

```
Sub CreateAndCompare()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim dic As Object
Dim ky As Variant

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("Impact")
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("D2"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each cl In rng
        If Not dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Value
        End If
    Next cl

    For Each ky In dic.keys
          lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("d2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
          Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = dic(ky)
          Cells(lastrow + 1, 32).Value = "Act-Plan"
          Cells(lastrow + 1, 33).Value = "Plan $000's"


          For i = 2 To 43
          mylookupvalue = Cells(lastrow + 1, 4) & "Actual $000's"
          mylookupvalue_2 = Cells(lastrow + 1, 4) & Cells(lastrow + 1, 33)
          myfirstcolumn = 33
          mylastcolumn = 43
          mycolumnIndex = i
          myfirstrow = 2
          mylastrow = lastrow
          mytablearray = Worksheets("Impact").Range(Cells(myfirstrow, myfirstcolumn), Cells(mylastrow, mylastcolumn))

          On Error Resume Next

          value_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mylookupvalue, mytablearray, mycolumnIndex, False)
          value_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mylookupvalue_2, mytablearray, mycolumnIndex, False)

          Cells(lastrow + 1, i + 32).Value = value_1 - value_2

          Cells(lastrow + 2, 4).Value = dic(ky)
          Cells(lastrow + 2, 32).Value = "Act-Fcst"
          Cells(lastrow + 2, 33).Value = "Forecast $000's"

          mylookupvalue_3 = Cells(lastrow + 2, 4) & "Actual $000's"
          mylookupvalue_4 = Cells(lastrow + 2, 4) & Cells(lastrow + 2, 33)

          value_3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mylookupvalue_3, mytablearray, mycolumnIndex, False)
          value_4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mylookupvalue_4, mytablearray, mycolumnIndex, False)

          Cells(lastrow + 2, i + 32).Value = value_3 - value_4

          Next i

    Next ky

    Worksheets("Impact").Range("AH2:BW10024").NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

End Sub
```

Comment: ① I recommend to avoid nested loops (in most cases this slows down a lot). ② Dont't use `On Error Resume Next` unless you know exactly how to use it correctly. This line just hides *all* error messages but the errors wont disappear, you just cannot see their messages. Errors that you cannot see, can't be fixed! For more info see [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling). ③ See my answer for a alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. Loop through all data rows
2. Find the rows plan/actual/forecast for the current impact no
3. Then write the calculations to the end of the worksheet

So you would end up with something like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateAndCompare()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Impact")

    'we assume here that the sheet is already sorted by column D "Impact #"

    Dim LastDataRow As Long 'find last used row
    LastDataRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim LastDataColumn As Long 'find last used column
    LastDataColumn = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim NextEmptyRow As Long
    NextEmptyRow = LastDataRow + 1

    Dim iRow As Long, PlanRow As Long, ActualRow As Long, ForcastRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastDataRow 'loop through all data rows
        Select Case ws.Cells(iRow, "AF").Value 'check which row type the current iRow is and remember
            Case "Plan $000's":     PlanRow = iRow
            Case "Actual $000's":   ActualRow = iRow
            Case "Forecast $000's": ForcastRow = iRow
        End Select

        'detect change of impact no
        If ws.Cells(iRow, "D").Value <> ws.Cells(iRow + 1, "D").Value Or iRow = LastDataRow Then
            'check if plan/actual/forecast rows were found (if one is missing we cannot calculate
            If PlanRow > 0 And ActualRow > 0 And ForcastRow > 0 Then
                'copy column A-AE to next 2 empty rows
                ws.Cells(NextEmptyRow, "A").Resize(RowSize:=2, ColumnSize:=31).Value = ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Resize(ColumnSize:=31).Value

                'write purpose
                ws.Cells(NextEmptyRow, "AF").Value = "Act - Plan"
                ws.Cells(NextEmptyRow + 1, "AF").Value = "Act - Fcst"

                'calculate
                Dim iCol As Long
                For iCol = 33 To LastDataColumn
                    ws.Cells(NextEmptyRow, iCol).Value = ws.Cells(ActualRow, iCol).Value - ws.Cells(PlanRow, iCol).Value
                    ws.Cells(NextEmptyRow + 1, iCol).Value = ws.Cells(ActualRow, iCol).Value - ws.Cells(ForcastRow, iCol).Value
                Next iCol


                NextEmptyRow = NextEmptyRow + 2 'initialize for next impact no
            End If

            PlanRow = 0: ActualRow = 0: ForcastRow = 0 'initialize for next impact no
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```